# UMVUE related problem for $Bernoulli(p)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution, parameter-estimation

$X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ follows iid $Bernoulli(p)$, $0<p<1$

Let $$ \tau(p)={(p+ qe^3)}^2 $$ is a function of parameter $p$ where $q=1-p$.

Q.1 $\:$ Write an unbiased estimator $T$ for $\tau(p)$

Q.2 $\:$ If $U=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ is the complete sufficient statistic, then calculate $E_p[T|U=u]$ using Lehmann-Schefee theorems

Q.3 $\:$ Find the UMVUE for $\tau(p)$.

($Hint:$ Use the concept of mgf of the Xs)

$\underline{\Large Solution}$:

1. I have chosen $T=e^{3(1-X_1)} \: e^{3(1-X_2)}$ which is unbiased for $\tau(p)$.
2. I have calculated $E_p[T|U=u]$ which is $$E_p[T|U=u]= e^6\: \frac{(n-u)(n-u-1)}{n(n-1)} + 2 e^3 \: \frac{u(n-u)}{n(n-1)} + \frac{u(u-1)}{n(n-1)}  $$

Now my questions are :

i.) Are my founding results correct?

ii.) Is it possible to simplify the resulting quantity of $E_p[T|U=u]$?

iii.) What is the answer to Q.3?

iv.) Please show me the Expectation of at least one of the three parts of $E_p[T|U=u]$

v.)  Should I choose $T=[X_1 + (1-X_1)e^3] \: [X_2 + (1-X_2)e^3]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure is correct and you calculations look fine to me.

**I did check only the first addend** of your conditional expectation:

$$\mathbb{P}[T=e^6|U=u]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[T=e^6]\mathbb{P}[\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i=u|X_1=0,X_2=0]}{\mathbb{P}[\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i=u]}=$$

$$=\frac{q^2\binom{n-2}{u}p^u q^{n-2-u}}{\binom{n}{u}p^uq^{n-u}}=\dots=\frac{(n-u)(n-u-1)}{n(n-1)}=(1-\overline{X}_n)(1-\frac{n}{n-1}\overline{X}_n)$$

Which is exactly your result and thus I have no doubts that the rest is correct too.

Finally calculate

$$\mathbb{E}[T|U]=1\cdot\mathbb{P}[T=1|U=u]+e^3\cdot\mathbb{P}[T=e^3|U=u]+e^6\cdot\mathbb{P}[T=e^6|U=u]$$

Q3
Using Lehmann Scheffé and Rao Blackwell results together, $\mathbb{E}[T|U]$ is  UMVUE for $\tau(p)$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your verification.